# Delphi Tchart is not showing all the items in the legend while printing

Tags: delphi, teechart

I am using Delphi Tchart to draw a graph based on my series data.
Here is my problem

I have placed the Tchart component in a panel and on filling the graph,  on  the panel legend of Tchart shows 30 items.   I am increasing the legend font size and  I have saved the Tchart to a .wmf file and using it to print the chart. on printing, I am not seeing all the items in the legend. If I see 30 values on the panel where I placed the Tchart, in the print I am seeing only 10 values. In the saved metafile also I see only 10 items in the legend. 
How can I make the .wmf file hold the Tchart without dropping the legend items?

And one more problem is I have 40 values drawn on to the graph and the legend shows only 20 items and if I increase the panel width I see more items in the legend. How can I make the legend automatically show all the items?

Comment: Doesn't look like it does multiple columns automatically for Left/Right position of the legend like it does for for Top/Bottom.

Comment: Thank you !! Is it a component issue then? Is it possible to make all the legend items display on the print with the selected font size?

Comment: You can check my solution for a similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73781273/4428219